# List not being displayed (using ListFragment and AsyncTask)

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, android-listfragment

I have a class (ListMainContentFragment) which extends ListFragment. Its purpose is to get JSON data and display it in a never ending list with a custom adapter. Initially, I had called both the Fragment and the AsyncTask from my main activity and that worked perfectly fine until I added the OnScrollListener because I need to call the AsyncTask again, from within the OnScrollListener. So I moved the entire AsyncTask code to within the ListFragment. Now, the JSON data is getting parsed but the list is not displayed. For some reason, the code thinks that the list has been displayed and the onScroll method is being called. No errors are being thrown. Code follows.

```
// List Fragment
public static class ListMainContentFragment extends ListFragment {
  public static final String ARG_DATA_TO_DISPLAY = "parsed_data";
  public static List<Result> currentResults;

  public ListMainContentFragment() {
    // Empty constructor
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    try {
      new GetJobsTask().execute(currentURL).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JobsListAdaptor adapter = new JobsListAdaptor(inflater.getContext(), currentResults);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
//  Integer rSize = adapter.getCount();
//  Log.i("Scroll", "List generating with "+rSize.toString()+" entries");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_of_jobs, container, false);
  }


  /** Start Handling JSON Data **/

  private class GetJobsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Result>> {
    AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");

    // Get JSON data, use JSONResponseHandler to parse into List of type Result
    @Override
    protected List<Result> doInBackground(String... url) {
      HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url[0]);
      JSONResponseHandler responseHandler = new JSONResponseHandler();
      try {
        return mClient.execute(request, responseHandler);
      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
    }

    // Close the Http client and log the number of results obtained.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Result> results) {
      if (mClient != null)
        mClient.close();
      currentResults = results;
      Log.i("onPostExecute", "There are "+results.size()+" entries");

    }
  }

  /** End Handling JSON Data **/

  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Log.i("Scroll", "OnViewCreated entered");
    ListView mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    Log.i("Scroll", "ListView accessed");
    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

      @Override
      public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // Auto-generated method stub
      }

      @Override
      public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        Log.i("Scroll", "List scrolled");
        switch(view.getId()) {
        case android.R.id.list:
          final Integer lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
          if ((lastItem == totalItemCount) & (preLast != lastItem)) {
            Log.i("Scroll", "Last item reached");
            currentURL = "http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=9616825572719411&v=2&format=json&l=austin&limit=10&start="+lastItem.toString();
            new GetJobsTask().execute(currentURL);
            preLast = lastItem;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my Logcat output:

```
05-31 17:57:39.245: I/Scroll(2559): OnViewCreated entered
05-31 17:57:39.245: I/Scroll(2559): ListView accessed
05-31 17:57:39.245: I/Scroll(2559): List scrolled
05-31 17:57:39.249: I/Scroll(2559): List scrolled
05-31 17:57:39.261: I/onPostExecute(2559): There are 20 entries
```

From the logcat info it looks like the onScroll method is being called even before onPostExecute has completed. And it is only within onPostExecute that I am assigning the results of the AsyncTask to the variable currentResults. I tried adding the get() method in order to force the main thread to wait for the AsyncTask to finish but it doesn't seem to be doing what I expected it to do.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you change the adapter content you should call:

```
getListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also you are not changing the adapter content itself. Try:

```
currentResults.clear();
currentResults.addAll(results);
getListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I made that change but it hasn't made any difference. That line will only be reached if I scroll to the end of the list but there is currently no list being displayed. So it doesn't really solve my current problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I see another problem. Note that the following line "   currentResults = results;" changing the reference of the list stored in a field of your fragment - you are not changing adapter content at all. Try to clear existing list, addAll and then notifyDataSetChanged.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, you are setting the list adapter before the AsyncTask has executed. This means that the list adapter *is* set, but there is nothing for it to display.

```
try {
    new GetJobsTask().execute(currentURL).get(); 
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// Because the AsyncTask is handled in another thread, it returns straight away,
// so this is called before the AsyncTask is finished.
JobsListAdaptor adapter = new JobsListAdaptor(inflater.getContext(), currentResults);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Instead, move this code into the onPostExecute method, like so:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Result> results) {
    if (mClient != null) {
        mClient.close();
    }
    JobsListAdaptor adapter = new JobsListAdaptor(inflater.getContext(), results);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    Log.i("onPostExecute", "There are "+results.size()+" entries");

}
```